# vsftpd works with ipv6 but not with ipv4

Tags: ftp, ipv6, vsftpd, ipv4

I am running an ftp server via vstfpd.

/etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
#connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=ftpuser
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO

pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
pasv_min_port=2212
pasv_max_port=2222
listen_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
listen_port=2211

userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.users
```

When I run vsftpd using "sudo vsftpd", I get the following error:

```
500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket
```

However, the server runs without any errors if I modify the first to lines of the config to look like this:

```
#listen=YES
listen_ipv6=YES
```

That being said, only clients that support ipv6 have been able to connect to the server. How do I get this server to successfully run on ipv4 mode?

Note: I am currently not using systemd or xinetd to run vsftpd and I have checked my system to make sure that no vsftpd service is running.

Comment: Check with `netstat -ta` that no process is already listening on the ftp port. You didn't mention which operating system you are running, but if you are on Linux, check what `systemctl net.ipv6.bindv6only` reports. If the bindv6only setting is 1, try changing it to 0 with `sudo systemctl net.ipv6.bindv6only=0`, disable `listen` and enable `listen_ipv6` in `vsftpd.conf`. This way a single IPv6 socket accepts connections using both IPv4 and IPv6.